# APS.NET Ошибка при чтении CSV файла

Tags: asp.net, csv, swagger

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь считать csv и вместо считанных строк
Swagger выдает

Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:

CORS
Network Failure
URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

"По моему даже студия крашнулась) Приложение сразу останавливает свою работу. Думал включение CORS поможет, но кажется не сработало. Подскажите - в чем может быть проблема"

```
//Контроллер
 [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class HomeController: ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ICSVService _csvService;

        public HomeController(ICSVService csvService)
        {
            _csvService = csvService;
        }

        
        [HttpPost("read-csv")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCSV([FromForm] IFormFileCollection file)
        {
            var dataFromFile = _csvService.ReadCSV<Values>(file[0].OpenReadStream());

            return Ok(dataFromFile);
        }
```

```
//Класс читатель)
 public class CSVServise : ICSVService
    {
        public IEnumerable<T> ReadCSV<T>(Stream file)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(file);
            var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            var records = csv.GetRecords<T>();
            return records;
        }
    }
```

```
//Program.cs
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICSVService, CSVServise>();
builder.Services.AddCors();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```